# Building ethminer on Win7 using CMake & VS2015

Tags: cpp-ethereum, ethminer, compilation, command-line, visual-studio

I'm trying to build [ethminer](https://github.com/Genoil/cpp-ethereum) on a windows box and am Visual Studio 2015 fails. The steps that I take are the following:

Download ethminer/cpp-ethereum and install dependencies using the command line prompt with Administrator privileges:

```
git clone https://github.com/Genoil/cpp-ethereum.git
cd extdep
getstuff.bat
```

So far, so good, now I create (I've [struggled](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32801638/cmake-error-at-cmakelists-txt30-project-no-cmake-c-compiler-could-be-found) a bit with CMake) the Visual Studio 2015 project solution files using CMake:

```
mkdir build
cd build
cmake.exe -DBUNDLE=cudaminer -G "Visual Studio 14 2015 Win64" ..
```

Everything seems okay (the solution files are generated) but when I try to build from VS I get a large number of errors:

```
Severity    Code    Description Project File    Line    Suppression State
Error   C2206   'swap': typedef cannot be used for function definition (compiling source file C:Ethereum-Miner\cpp-ethereum\libdevcore\Common.cpp)  devcore C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 14.0\VC\include\utility  21  
Error   C2988   unrecognizable template declaration/definition (compiling source file C:Ethereum-Miner\cpp-ethereum\libdevcore\Common.cpp)  devcore C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 14.0\VC\include\utility  35  
Error   C2059   syntax error: ')' (compiling source file C:Ethereum-Miner\cpp-ethereum\libdevcore\Common.cpp)   devcore C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 14.0\VC\include\utility  35  
Error   C2065   '_Ty': undeclared identifier (compiling source file C:Ethereum-Miner\cpp-ethereum\libdevcore\Common.cpp)    devcore C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 14.0\VC\include\utility  50  
Error   C2923   'std::is_nothrow_move_constructible': '_Ty' is not a valid template type argument for parameter '_Ty' (compiling source file C:Ethereum-Miner\cpp-ethereum\libdevcore\Common.cpp)   devcore C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 14.0\VC\include\utility  50  
Error   C2923   'std::is_nothrow_move_assignable': '_Ty' is not a valid template type argument for parameter '_Ty' (compiling source file C:Ethereum-Miner\cpp-ethereum\libdevcore\Common.cpp)  devcore C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 14.0\VC\include\utility  50
```

Also, I can't seem to find the compiler configuration details (it seems like the CXX compiler is not being used).

Comment: I'm having the exact same problem.  Did you ever find a solution for this?

Comment: Yes, use an earlier version of Visual Studio.

Comment: I was able to get it to compile under vs2015 by switching all the projects to the "Visual Studio 2013 (v120)" toolset (project / properties).